# Do I have enough Watts?

Tags: power-supply

I have a 700 Watt PSU and my graphics card needs 550 W.  How can I know if I have enough power left over for the rest of the hardware?

Specs:

- mobo: Asus psx68d premium
- RAM: 12 GB DD3 triple channel
- Zalman cooler for the CPU
- CPU: Core i7 930
- GPU: Nvidia GTX 465
- 4 case fans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My read of specs for a GTX465 based card says 250 Watts for the card itself - MAX.  I think the 550 watts figure you got was for the WHOLE SYSTEM, not just the card.  It looks like you have 450 watts for the rest of your system, and that should be plenty.  I don't see it going over about 200, even with a couple of disks and maybe some other cards.  You should be fine, with several hundred watts to spare.

Comment: Great.  I forgot to mention 2 SATA disks and 1 SSD (SATA).  Thanks for the vote of confidence, I'll stick to my PSU.

Comment: Most consumer sata disks only run about 10-15 watts and the SSD way less so that should be no problem.

Answer (score 3):

PSU manufactures have online power requirement estimators. E.g. from Antec: http://www.antec.outervision.com/

Enter your system configuration and see what it says.